# block (not move to spam) messages in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, blocking

We're doing automated testing of a website and I'm getting tons of freaking e-mails from the website. I tried adding them to blocked list but they just go to the junk e-mail folder. How can I bock them? I'm using Outlook 2007 with Exchange Server.

Comment: Sounds like you need to block them at the server level.  Reject all emails from the following domain i imagine?

Comment: I think part of the problem is the sender is on the same domain as my e-mail is.

Comment: Ah.  Unless im mistaken, Exchange/outlook specifically say that blocking that is NOT allowed...

Comment: If there is any sort of repeatable pattern (sender name, subject, content, ect.) you can block them by creating a rule in Outlook (Tools -> Rules and Alerts) and applying it to your inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the server took some time before it started blocking them. At any rate they've stopped now.